# Iteratively filtering DICTIONARY.COLUMNS - SAS

Tags: sas

*(For context, I'm working with the `DICTIONARY.COLUMNS` [dataset](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/070-30.pdf) - this is huge and operations with it are running incredibly slowly.)*

I've got a dataset `my_datasets`, with a single column, `dataset`, which gives the names of SAS datasets which I am interested in. I wish to extract the `DICTIONARY.COLUMNS` entries which relate to these datasets.

This feels like it would usually be a job for a `LEFT JOIN` but this is taking far too long to run (I haven't successfully had it run yet). A filter on `DICTIONARY.COLUMNS` runs instantly in comparison.

As such, I'm wondering if there is a way I can iterate through each of the names in the `my_datasets` dataset, into a filter statement, and append all the results.

Open to other approaches also.

This is the code I'm using to filter:

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE work.dictionary as
SELECT  
libname as LIBRARY, 
memname as DATASET, 
name as VARIABLE_NAME, 
type, 
length, 
format, 
label 
FROM DICTIONARY.COLUMNS
WHERE memname in ("dataset_name") /* Replace this value */
;
QUIT;
```

Comment: Looks like an easy job with `call execute`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before going for an iterating approach, you can create a csv list of quoted memnames from `my_datasets`.  This list can be used in a filtering `IN`

```
proc sql;
  reset noprint;
  select quote(trim(dataset)) into :target_dataset_names separated by ','
  from my_datasets
  ;

  create table work.my_dictionary as
  select ...
  from dictionary.columns
  where memname in (&target_dataset_names)
  ;
```

you might want to target the candidate libraries by also filtering on libname

```
  and libname in ('PROJECT1', 'ROSSDATA', 'WORK')
```

Remote librefs is also one contributor to long running dictionary queries.